# I want to initialize DateTime in EST and then convert to Universal TIme

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I want to initialize DateTime in Eastern Standard Time and then convert to universal time.

I have One DateTime (CurrentDT) whose TimeZone is not set, but it is in EST.
it is parsedExact from following sting

> "ddd, d MMM yyyy H:mm:ss"

I have written following code to solve the problem.

```
  TimeZoneInfo currentTimeZone=null;
  currentTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");      
  CurrentDT=TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(CurrentDT, currentTimeZone);
  CurrentDT = CurrentDT.ToUniversalTime();
```

The Problem is that it looks like i am doing wrong. I am converting DateTime,which is in local time zone to Eastern Standerd Time and then to universal standard Time.
I don't know how can i initialize TimeZone of CurrentDt initially.
Kindly help me understand Thankyou.

Comment: Where is `CurrentDT` first assigned?

Comment: _I have One DateTime (CurrentDT) whose TimeZone is not set, but it is in EST_ What do you mean with this sentence exactly? A `DateTime` is timezone _awareness_. This `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` can be different behaviour based on `Kind` property of `CurrentDT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember well, `DateTime` doesn't preserve info about `TimeZone`, but if you know that a certain `DateTime` is in a specific `TimeZone` you can get the UTC from it doing something like this:

```
var UtcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(CurrentDt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time")); // 1st param is the date to convert and the second is its TimeZone
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you could use (relatively) new type `DateTimeOffset`, like here:

```
var est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
var offset = est.GetUtcOffset();
var dataTimeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(dateTimeWithoutOffset, offset);
var result = dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime;
```

Since you should work in different time zones, `DateTimeOffset` can make your code more clear.